# Removing common words from a searched for string PHP

Tags: php, string, comparison

OK, so I have a string of words delimited by space i.e.

$commonwords = 'a,an,and,I,it,is,do,does,for,from,go,how,the,etc';

And I receive a search query from $_POST['searchquery'];

I want to remove any common words from the search string, what I am looking for as an end result will be more concise keywords that I can then use to query the database.

So if the user searches for "How do I search for files"

The string becomes "search files" when all common words are removed.

Comment: The term you're looking for, by the way, is "stop words."  No, I don't know why it's called stop words.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will work but you will have to add the capitalized "how" to your $commonwords

```
$commonwords = 'a,an,and,I,it,is,do,does,for,from,go,how,the,etc';

$commonwords = explode(",", $commonwords);


$search = "How do I search for files";

$search = explode(" ", $search);

foreach($search as $value){
    if(!in_array($value, $commonwords)){
        echo "$value<br/>";
        $query[] = $value;
    }
}   


    $query = implode(" ", $query);

    echo $query;
?>
```

Comment: Yeah I was thinking about case matching and will probably just use strtoupper on both $commonwords and the $searchquery. Awesome answer though and very quick. Can't think for crap today - think I'm still suffering a New years day hangover, anyway I appreciate your help man!

Comment: @Kai You're welcome.  Please choose my answer as the official solution if you like it the best.

Comment: array_diff() would have saved your time

Comment: @Letmesee  Cool.  I didn't know about that function.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a lib to remove stop words: [Remove Stop Words](https://github.com/rap2hpoutre/remove-stop-words). You can use it like this:

```
echo remove_stop_words('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog');
// quick brown fox jumps   lazy dog
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this ([CodePad](http://codepad.org/zAsxT7MZ)):

```
<?php

$commonwords = 'a,an,and,I,it,is,do,does,for,from,go,how,the,etc';
$commonwords = explode(',', $commonwords);

$_POST['searchquery'] = "How do I search for files";
$_POST['searchquery'] = explode(' ', $_POST['searchquery']);
echo implode(' ', array_udiff($_POST['searchquery'], $commonwords, 'strcasecmp'));
```

It first explodes both strings (your list, and the query) into workable arrays. Then it filters the differences and outputs the imploded array.

Output:

```
search files
```

Answer (score 1):

For better result, convert common words and search words in to lower or upper case, here I used lowercase,

```
<?php
$commonwords = 'a,an,and,i,it,is,do,does,for,from,go,how,the,etc';

$commonwords = explode(",", $commonwords);


$search = strtolower("How do I search for files");

$search = explode(" ", $search);

foreach($search as $value){
    if(!in_array($value, $commonwords)){
       $query[] = $value;
    }
} 

    $query = implode(" ", $query);

    echo $query; // this is output
?>
```

Comment: Personally I'd lower the case within the foreach, this would make it possible to search something in case, but still remove words that are uncased in the list.